# Cassandra Reaper sidecar implications for local quorum

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes

I am preparing to run Cassandra Reaper 3.5.0 against Cassandra 4.1.x as a sidecar in a Kubernetes Pod (in a single Cassandra cluster).

Is there any potential, given that, for inconsistent data across DCs when LOCAL_QUORUM is used consistently, if the hints window isn't exceeded?